# SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue Not Returning Correct Results

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqlcommand, parameterized-query

I'll admit that I'm a bit of a newbie (though learning fast!) when it comes to using parameterized queries in C#, so I'm probably just overlooking something here, but I can't seem to figure out how to get a parameterized query to work for me.

Here is a much simplified example. If more information is needed, I am certainly willing to supply it.

```
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Sites WHERE ((STATE LIKE '@STATE'));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", "MA");

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]);
    }
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Using SQL Server Profiler, I can see that the following query is being issued:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Sites WHERE ((STATE LIKE ''@STATE''))',N'@STATE nvarchar(2)',@STATE=N'MA'
```

If I run that query directly in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns 0. If, however, I modify the query like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Sites WHERE ((STATE LIKE ''MA''))',N'@STATE nvarchar(2)',@STATE=N'MA'
```

And run it, I get a count of 51 back, which is correct.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need quotes around @STATE

Comment: Great, thanks. I knew it was going to be an easy one.

A quick followup: Now I can't seem to get a LIKE clause to work correctly. How would you write a "begins with" clause?

I currently have:

   command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Sites WHERE ((STATE LIKE '@STATE%'";

but am again getting a 0 count back. I'm sure this one is simple as well...

Answer (score 4):

You just need to unquote your parameter in the SQL statement (quoting text makes SQL Server treat it as a literal). Change this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Sites WHERE ((STATE LIKE '@STATE'));
```

to this:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Sites WHERE ((STATE LIKE @STATE));
```